# How to set permissions in SharePoint 2010 using jquery and SPServices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, permissions, spservices

I am able to fetch the details of users and their roles through SPServices. Below is the link that I reffered.

https://devspoint.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/get-user-roles-using-jquery-and-spservices/

Is there any way if I can grant/revoke permissions to any SharePoint list items using jquery and SPServices ?

Comment: I dont think its possible using jquery

Comment: I believe you can do it to lists but not items

Comment: How can you do it to lists?